# Loop over a view's controls in SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

I would like to know whether there is a way to loop over all the controls in a view (or all controls under a specific control) in SAPUI5. I'm looking for an analog to the vanilla JS document.body.querySelectorAll('*') function.

The closest thing I know of would be the View class's getControlsByFieldGroupId method but that would require me to tag all elements in the view, which I'd rather not. I've looked in the [API reference](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api) to no avail.

Is there some clean way to do this in SAPUI5 1.71?

Thanks in advance for your input!
Joshua Schroijen

Comment: It's is possible.But IDs are a composition within ui5. From where would you like to call this, (controller method?). What's your give initial information?

Comment: I would like to call this from the controller linked to the view's onInit method

Comment: What is the user case? What are you actually trying to achieve by collecting all the view children?

Comment: I'd like to check if any input in the view is editable (which is determined by a table in the back-end) and in that case enable a button.
It sounds silly but the view in question contains forms that sometimes change and maintainability-wise it'd be nice if the future maintainer wouldn't need to worry about adding certain attributes to inputs or certain lines to the controller code.
It's no hard requirement but I'm interested in whether it can be done.

Comment: So you have a backen table, controlling form inputs and these "table" entries are read by the app via odata. Why would you not simply use the data within the odata service?

Answer (score -1):

You can try: YourViewInstance.findAggregatedObjects(true); which will return all the aggregated controls.